# why nobody figures out that Superman and Clark Kent are the same person?

Tags: dc, superman

Anybody that knows Clark Kent would immediately realizes that he is Superman (Superman doesn't wear a mask, it's a huge 6"3' guy, the only difference is that he wears glasses when in 'Clark Kent mode', what is the explanation for nobody noticing that both men are alike?)

Comment: Also, with current face recognition software, matching the both of them would be a matter of minutes...

Comment: It's true that *most* people don't realize this, but there *have* been people who have figured it out over the course of all the different Superman canons.

Comment: Not the answer, obviously, but I sometimes think SNL had it right years ago with their skit that everyone actually knew, but it was the running joke that everyone just 'played along' to trick Clark into thinking he was actually fooling people by putting on the glasses.

Answer (score 5):

I remember reading, long ago, about this same thing. And the answer that was given by someone who worked on the comic (I'll try to find a link) is that it's a matter of perception. When you see Clark Kent, you see a nerdy, bumbling, clumsy, slouchy person. Yet when you see Superman, you see a tall, handsome, confident, strong man. In the minds of people who know Clark, how could he ever be Superman?

Essentially, his disguise is being everything Superman isn't. So subconsciously, you think there could never be any association.

Comment: It's worth noting that in some versions, this is explicitly a use of his supercontrol over his own body: he can change everything about his body language and even subtly reshape his face through fine muscle control.